# Redirect timer on successful WebForm submition

Tags: webforms, redirection

I'm asked to introduce auto-redirect (to the home page) on the confirmation page of WebForm (i.e. when user sends data, he gets on the page saying "Thank you! You submition has been received, etc..." ). And I'm asked to make a redirect after some time having past, let,s say, 10 seconds.

Seems that I have to introduce some js altering but I don't know how to do this properly.

Thank you!

Comment: I think you have to write the js code only for the page that you get after redirection.. Moreover you may have to write the redirect code from submission page to home page in js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code in `webform-confirmation.tpl.php`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var delay = 10 ;
  var url = "http://google.com";
  function countdown() {
  setTimeout(countdown, 1000) ;
  $('.webform-confirmation').html("Redirecting in "  + delay  + " seconds.");
  delay --;
  if (delay < 0 ) {
  window.location = url ;
  delay = 0 ;
  }
 }
countdown() ;
});
```

Comment: I get this error from Firebug:  

`$(document).ready(function() {` -- `$ is not a function`. Why?

Comment: Well, for some reason there should have been `jQuery(...)` instead of `$(...)`. Thanks!

Comment: You should always wrap you script with `(function ($) { // Here is your script })(jQuery);` For more information about using JavaScript in Drupal 7: visit https://drupal.org/node/756722

Answer (score 1):

Well if you are new in drupal I will explain it to you step by step:

1. first create a file in 'sites/all/themes/yourtheme/js/' called auto_redirection.js and inside of it paste the code above. (if you do not have the js folder just create one!)
2. create a file in 'sites/all/themes/yourtheme/templates' called webform-confirmation-'form id'.tpl.php without the quotes, optional you can just let it webform-confirmation.tpl.php and it will be applied to all the webforms confirmations.
3. go to 'sites/all/modules/webform/templates/webform-confirmation.tpl.php' and copy the content of that file and paste it into your own webform-confirmation-'form id'.tpl.php you already created.

3.Inside the file webform-confirmation-'form id'.tpl.php just add this at the end

`drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'yourtheme') . '/js/auto_redirection.js');`

do not forget to replace 'yourtheme' for the name of your theme or subtheme... and put the php tags for the above code, for some reason I cannot write the php tags here jeje.

Thats all you need hope it helps someone

Answer (score 0):

Use this script instead if you want to display a thank you message and the counter in the message.

```
    var counter = 10;
setInterval(function() {
    counter--;
    if(counter < 0) {
        window.location = 'http://www.google.com';
    } else {
        document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = counter;
         }
}, 1000);​
```

add a span with id=count at the message to display the counter.

if found the script here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12498244/3357085